Automated Tattoo Image Tagging
I’m looking to develop a system that tags tattoo images using a predefined list of approximately 200 keywords.
The system must:
Operate entirely offline, with all models and data stored locally.
Use open-source frameworks (preferably with an MIT-style license).
Run efficiently on a local gaming PC equipped with an RTX 4070 GPU (16 GB VRAM).
Additionally, it would be great if the system could tag the body locations of the tattoos using a predefined list of 20 locations.
Given these requirements, which models and frameworks would you recommend for this task?

Asking for solutions to big projects is too broad. Ask a more specific question. What are your findings so far? How much do you know about AI? Do you know the difference between classification and regression? Or object detection vs image classification, for example? Please, edit your post to share more about your knowledge and findings so far.
